# Django settings.py + dj_database_url on Heroku?

Tags: django, heroku

Im following the getting started with Django on Heroku - and it shows to set up dj_database_url...

```
DATABASES = {'default': dj_database_url.config(default='postgres://localhost')}
```

Am I supposed to leave this exactly as above? thats what I did - and my site appears to work just fine...

OR

Am I supposed to swap out something in the above with DATABASE_URL - which gets pulled from the heroku config set ups?

With not using DATABASE_URL anywhere -- it appears to be working on heroku with the above set up and no change.... but when I look at the DB with a pg:info - I get 0 connections... which makes me think there is no connection to the postgresql -- but hows it working then??

I don't quite understand yet how dj_database_url is working on Heroku with this...can anyone shed a bit more light on this?

```
heroku pg:info
=== HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_GOLD_URL (DATABASE_URL)
Plan:        Dev
Status:      available
Connections: 0
PG Version:  9.1.6
Created:     2012-10-07 16:11 UTC
Data Size:   6.6 MB
Tables:      12
Rows:        27/10000 (In compliance)
Fork/Follow: Unavailable
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is correct as-is.

When running on Heroku, there is an environment variable set (`DATABASE_URL`) which contains the database URL (a string like `postgres://`, but with a long autogenerated username/password/database-name, and the host is on amazonaws usually)

When running locally, `DATABASE_URL` is not set, so your `default = '...'` database URL is used instead (allows you to run the code locally for development, and deploy to Heroku, without changing any code).

This is based on the ["12factor methodology"](http://www.12factor.net/) (the whole document pretty much describes how Heroku is structured)

The `dj_database_url.config` just parses the username/password/host/db-name from the URL, and splits it into the [dictionary format expected by Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#databases) - [the code](https://github.com/kennethreitz/dj-database-url/blob/master/dj_database_url.py) is rather simple, if you are curious

Comment: thanks!  what about the pg:info returning 0 connections? wouldn't the application wired up be at least one connection?

Comment: @tbarbe Not sure, I guess it depends if the DB API keeps a persistant connection open?